# What is the category tag in the PEAR standard coding style for?

Tags: php, coding-style, phpcodesniffer

The PEAR coding style [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) requires a tag `category` to be defined for each class (see especially  [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.header.php)). But what is the meaning of this `category` tag, as I cannot find a definition or a real example for `category`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775463/what-is-the-purpose-of-these-phpdoc-properties

Comment: I think it denotes where it belongs if it makes it [here](http://pear.php.net/packages.php)